# Modifying Every Column of Every Frame of a Video

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing

I would like to write a program that will take a video as input, create an output video file, and will (starting after a certain number of frames), begin writing modified frames to the output file frame by frame.
The modification will need to work on individual columns of pixels, one at a time.

Viewing this as a problem to be solved in Matlab, with each frame as a matrix... I cannot think of a way to make this **computationally tractable**.
I am hoping that someone might be able to offer suggestions on how I might begin to approach this problem.

---

Here are some details, in case it helps:

I'm interested in transforming a video in the following way:

Viewing a video as a sequence of (MxN) matrices, where each matrix is called a `frame`:

- Take an input video and create new file for output video
- For each column V in frame(i) of output video, replace this column by
  column V in `frame(i + V - N)` of the input video.

For example: the new right-most column (column N) of frame(i) will contain column N of `frame(i + N - N) = frame(i)...` so that there is no replacement. The new 2nd to right-most column (column N-1) of frame(i) will contain column N-1 of `[frame(i+N-1-N) = frame(i-1)]`.

In order to make this work (i.e. in order to not run out of previous frames), this column replacement will start on frame N of the video.

Comment: Is this an assignment or had you asked (but then deleted) this question before?

Comment: Schorsch, I posted this question about a week ago, but it was extremely unclear what I was actually asking. The last question was closed for this reason... it seemed that I was asking something like "what language would be best to use for this problem?" My intended question is: "CAN I use Matlab for this problem... and in general how can I possibly start on this problem?" This is not an assignment, but rather a transformation I would like to apply to a video. I've been editing videos to **approximate** this effect by hand in Adobe Premiere... but this would save me an enormous amount of time

Comment: If there is still any doubt about what I am asking: I am **not** asking for an algorithm to accomplish the specific task I have described in the second half of my post. Rather, I am asking how I can start processing videos at this 'fine-grained' level without either running out of memory or having to wait several years to see the program finish.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the additional - and helpful - background information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... This is basically a variable delay running from left to right?

As you say, you do have two ways of going about this:

a) Use lots of memory
b) Use lots of file access

Your memory requirements increase as a cube power of the size of the video - the size of each frame increases, AND the number of previous frames you need to have open or reference increases. I.e. doubling frame size will require 4x memory per frame, and 2x number of frames open.

I think that Matlab's memory management will probably make this hard to do for e.g. a 1080p video, unless you have a pretty high-end workstation. Do you? A quick test-read of a 720p video gives 1.2MB per frame. 1080p would then be approx 5MB per frame, and you would need to have 1920 frames open: approx 10GB needed.

It will be more efficient to load frames individually, if you don't have enough memory - otherwise you will be using pagefiles and that'll be slower than loading frame-by-frame.

Your basic code reading each frame individually could be something like this:

```
VR=VideoReader('My_Input_Video_Filename.avi');
VW=VideoWriter('My_Output_Video_Filename.avi','MPEG-4');

NumInFrames=get(VR,'NumberOfFrames');
InWidth=get(VR,'Width');
InHeight=get(VR,'Height');

OutFrame=zeros(InHeight,InWidth,3,'uint8');
for (frame=InWidth+1:NumInFrames)
    for (subindex=1:InWidth)
        CData=read(VR,frame-subindex);
        OutFrame(:,subindex,:)=CData(:,subindex,:);
    end
    writeVideo(VW,OutFrame);
end
```

This will probably be slow, and I haven't fully checked it works, but it does use a minimum amount of memory.

The best case for minimum file acess is probably using a ring buffer arrangement and the maximum amount of memory, which would look something like this:

```
VR=VideoReader('My_Input_Video_Filename.avi');
VW=VideoWriter('My_Output_Video_Filename.avi','MPEG-4');

NumInFrames=get(VR,'NumberOfFrames');
InWidth=get(VR,'Width');
InHeight=get(VR,'Height');

CDatas=read(VR,InWidth);
BufferIndex=1;
OutFrame=zeros(InHeight,InWidth,3,'uint8');
for (frame=InWidth+1:NumInFrames)
    CDatas(:,:,:,BufferIndex)=read(VR,frame);
    tempindices=circshift(1:InWidth,[1,-1*BufferIndex]);
    for (subindex=1:InWidth)
        OutFrame(:,subindex,:)=CDatas(:,subindex,:,tempindices(subindex));
    end
    writeVideo(VW,OutFrame);
    BufferIndex=mod(BufferIndex+1,InWidth);
end
```

The buffer indexing code may need some tweaking there, but something along those lines would be a minimum file access, maximum memory use solution.

For a given PC with more or less memory, you can implement somewhere in between these two as a solution (i.e. reading somewhere between 1 and all frames per iteration) as a best-case.

Matlab will be quite slow for this kind of task, but it will be a good way of getting your algorithm right and working out indexing bugs and that kind of thing. Converting to a compiled language would give a good increase in speed - I converted a Matlab script to a C# program in a couple of hours, and gave a 10x increase in speed over an optimised script where the time taken was in the number of file reads.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: +1 for the detail & effort, especially outlining two possible approaches

Comment: Thanks! It's an interesting question, I've done a little video processing in matlab before, and would like to again, so nice to think through a few problems :)